# Make AWS EC2 instances communicate with each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have two AWS EC2 instances: one has a Python program on it and the second one has a web application. Both instances run Ubuntu. With the web application, the user should be able to do the following tasks:

- Start the Python program ( and the instance if it is shutdown )
- Get status update on the process
- Kill the process

I though about using Lambda functions but it would be expensive. Any ideas on how i can do it?

Comment: I would suggest you to use the lambda for executing the Python program. That way, you don't need to handle the lifecycle of another EC2 (start/stop/status check)

In fact API gateway+Lambda can create the solution you are looking https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example.html

Comment: Yes it would be ok start the process with lambda but then to check the status, the web application will set a lot of get requests to check the status ( with ajax once every 5sec when the page is open ) which is why i would rather avoid lambda